# What's wrong in my code below, I am not getting output

Tags: extjs, extjs3

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
<!-- locally referred ExtJS library files -->
          <link href="ExtjsLib/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" 
          <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtjsLib/ext-all.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="ExtjsLib/ext-base.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript"> Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = "ExtjsLib/s.gif"; </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             Ext.onReady(function() {
             Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                renderTo: 'helloWorldPanel',
                height: 200,
                width: 600,
                title: 'Hello world',
                html: 'First Ext JS Hello World Program'
                });
             });
        </script>   
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="helloWorldPanel" /> 
       </body>
    </html>
```

What's wrong in my code.I am using ExtJS 3.4.1 version and I have referred the Extjs library files locally from 'ExtLib' folder. Its displaying just the blank page as output. please help.

Comment: I dont see any code, only commented lines

Comment: I have not put any comments in my code, just to post here i used them

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser debug console?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
<!-- locally referred ExtJS library files
```

should be this

```
<!-- locally referred ExtJS library files -->
```

If you don't close the comment everything is a comment.

Comment: I have not put any comments in my code, just to post here i used them

Answer (score 0):

Use Library Ext.all.debug.js instead of ext.base.js.